# ajax post fails sometimes if tries to post in small intervals with a large form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

The below ajax calls fails sometimes and I'm getting an error like net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. I have a large form with around 700 fields. There is a save button to save. But if I click the save button again and again after completing one post it fails sometimes.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://example.com',
        data: $( '#frm' ).serialize(),
        method: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
        }, 
        error: function(data, exception) { 
        },
    });
```

Comment: What is exactly your question?

Comment: ajax post not working sometimes and giving that error @KIKOSoftware

Comment: That is not a question, it's an observation. One that we cannot [hope to reproduce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) given the minimal code in your question.

Comment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET what is the reason for this ? is it because of large form fields data or server issue or php side issue ? what else details you need ?  @KIKOSoftware.

Comment: you can try to set data manually Ex: `data1:{$('.form-field.data1').val()}` then set the class for example only 20 fields. do that for all fields to the end of form. In this case you call ajax 14 times(for 700 fields) and you can set a little delay between them.

Comment: It seems to "caused" by Chrome not being able to connect. There are many possible reasons for this, as you assume. Do you actually wait for the previous form submission to complete before you press the save button again?

Comment: I can reproduce it firefox as well. Yes, the save button only active if the previous ajax calls complete. So yes @KIKOSoftware

Comment: I assume the error message is slightly different in Firefox? My best guess would be that it is a server side issue. The browser cannot connect to the URL specified in your AJAX call. Why? Who knows. This requires debugging. Start with a very simple PHP script to process the form, one that basically does nothing and returns immediately. Does the problem still occur? If it is then there's something wrong with the server config. If it is not you slowly add stuff to the PHP script until the problem occurs again. By removing and adding code like this you can probably find the offending bit of code.

Comment: It is also not a bad idea to check the error logs of your webserver. Does it show any errors?